# Error when i include my logger class

Tags: c++, logging, boost, compilation

I try to use boost log, i create a simple class
logger.hpp

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H

//#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
#include <string>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_file_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>


#define MAX_FILE_SIZE 25*1024*1024

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

class Logger {
    protected:
        void init();
    public:
        Logger();
        static void trace(std::string);
        static void debug(std::string);
        static void info(std::string);
        static void warning(std::string);
        static void error(std::string);
        static void fatal(std::string);
};
#endif
```

and logger.cpp

```
#include "header/logger.hpp"

Logger::Logger() {
this->init();
    logging::add_common_attributes();
}

void Logger::init () {
    logging::add_file_log
        (
         keywords::file_name = "sgoauth_%N.log",
         keywords::rotation_size = MAX_FILE_SIZE
        );
    logging::core::get()->set_filter
        (
         logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
        );
}


void Logger::trace(std::string tra) {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << tra;
}
void Logger::debug(std::string deb) {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << deb;
}
void Logger::info(std::string inf) {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << inf;
}
void Logger::warning(std::string war) {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << war;
}
void Logger::error(std::string err) {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << err;
}
void Logger::fatal(std::string fat) {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << fat;
}
```

When i create a simple main and i compile i have not any error but when i add just include in my project i have error show in the pastbin link

http://pastebin.com/y8StTrPD

My cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
#Déclaration du projet
project(sgoauth)
#Define PATH
#Boost
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /home/msouadji/lib/boost/include/)
set(BOOST_ROOT /home/msouadji/lib/boost/)
#Build Netlib
set ( CPP-NETLIB /home/msouadji/lib/cpp-netlib-fix-build )
#Placez vos exécutables dans des dossiers portant le nom du type de compilation
#(Release, Debug...).
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ./${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/)
#include BOOST
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK)
set(Boost_COMPONENTS log thread date_time regex filesystem system log_setup REQUIRED)
find_package( Boost 1.53 REQUIRED ${Boost_COMPONENTS} )
find_package( OpenSSL )
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
#include CPP-NETLIB
set ( CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} ${CPP-NETLIB} )
find_package ( cppnetlib 0.11.0 REQUIRED )
include_directories ( ${CPPNETLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
#C++11
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11" )
find_package( OpenSSL )
if (OPENSSL_FOUND)
    add_definitions(-DBOOST_NETWORK_ENABLE_HTTPS)
    include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

SET(source_files src/authloadconf.cpp src/authserver.cpp src/serverhandler.cpp
    src/authhandler.cpp  src/app.cpp src/httpclient.cpp src/httpsclient.cpp
    src/request.cpp src/nfcapphandler.cpp src/unixclient.cpp
    src/header/authexception.hpp src/logger.cpp)
#sgoauth
add_executable(sgoauth  ${source_files} src/sgoauth_main.cpp)
target_link_libraries ( sgoauth
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
    ${CPPNETLIB_LIBRARIES}
    pthread
    )

# quicktest
set(VAR httpclienttest  loggertest)
# loop over a, b,c with the variable f
foreach(exec ${VAR})
    add_executable(${exec}  ${source_files} src/quicktest/${exec}_main.cpp)
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( ${exec}
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
        ${CPPNETLIB_LIBRARIES}
        pthread
        )
endforeach(exec)
```

I do not know where is probleme my project use asio and cpp-netlib library can you help me please?

Comment: How can you include everything but the error message in your post?  Please edit your post with the error message.

Comment: Looks like you are using two different versions of BOOST.  This may be better posted on a Boost discussion board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using Boost Spirit V2 and Boost Phoenix V3 (the latter likely indirectly used by Boost Log).

To avoid conflicts **and** to get the improved Phoenix implementation define

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
```

**before** including **any** boost headers, or compile with `-DBOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3`